# Using TYPO3 form-framework: Content-Element on Summary-Page and in E-Mails

Tags: typo3, formframework

I made a form with the form-framework in TPYO3 12.4 that uses Content-Elements. The Content-Elements shows up in the form as expected, but not on the summary-Page and in Emails.

I configured my yaml-setup with a condition to show up the Content-Elements

```
        ContentElement:
           variants:
             -
               identifier: hide-1
               renderingOptions:
                 enabled: true
               condition: 'stepType == "SummaryPage" || finisherIdentifier in ["EmailToSender", "EmailToReceiver"]'
             -
              identifier: template-variant
              condition: 'getRootFormProperty("renderingOptions.templateVariant") == "version2"'
              properties:
                outerContainerClassAttribute: clearfix
```

In my html-Template I use a condition
<f:if condition="{0: formValue.element.type} == {0: 'ContentElement'}">

{formValue.element.properties.contentElementUid}

that outputs - of course - the Uid and not the content. Using <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_form.contentElementRendering">{element.properties.contentElementUid}</f:cObject> has no result.

Is there a way to show up on summarypages/in emails?

The usage of ce is necessary, because the statictext-Element will be overriden in the form-yaml-file if the backend-editor is used and I couldn't find a way to prevent it.